# Jquery move to other div ( animate )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs:

**CSS**

```
  #home {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #000;
  }

  .step1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 500px;
  }

  .step1 a{
    background: #AAF75A;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding: 14px 49px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 20px;
  }


  #about {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3000px;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #000;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="home">
<article>
  <div class="step1"><a class="move" href="#about">Let's go</a></div>
</article>
</div>


<div id="about">
<article>
  <div class="step1"><a class="move" href="#home">Next !?</a></div>
</article>
</div>
```

and I want move from `div id="home"` to `div id="about"`

I have this

**JS**

```
$(function($){
   $('a.move').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          _href = $this.attr('href'),
          dest  = $(_href).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({  scrollTop: dest}, 400 );
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

but it just goes down ... it doesn't move to the about div

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll to the left as well.  Like this:

```
$(function ($) {
    $('a.move').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            _href = $this.attr('href'),
            destX = $(_href).offset().top;
            destY = $(_href).offset().left;
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: destX,
            scrollLeft: destY            
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9NXfk/)**

Comment: thank you so much !! it's work fine but when i test it on my PC  file:///C:/.../Bureau/test.html  ... it's move in 1 sec and i use (.animate({         
        }, 4000);)

Comment: ok, mark the question as answered and ask another question.  The new question is about why it takes 1 second when you have 4000 as your speed parameter?

Comment: Yes that what i mean , and I'm very sorry I hope that you accept the apology on the delay in the response

Comment: That's OK, just ask it as a different question and choose an answer for this one.